# How do I change the color of user keywords in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

Syntax highlighting of user keywords in Visual Studio 2012 is done by copying a file named "usertype.dat" to the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE".

One use of this feature is to add coloring to CUDA specific keywords (__syncthreads(), threadIdx, blockIdx, etc.)

In Visual Studio 2010, the setting to change the color of user keywords was in Tool / Options / font and colors / Display items / user keywords. It's not there in Visual Studio 2012.

How do I change the color of user keywords in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 3):

The setting changed name in Visual Studio 2012. It was previously named "user keywords" and it's now called "C/C++ User Keywords".

Also, make sure the "usertype.dat" file is copied to 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE" and not
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"